# How to query a book with no author in a many-to-many scenario

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have the following database design in relating books and authors:

Books(bookid,title)
Authors(authorid,authorname)
BooksAuthors(bookid,authorid)

I have no problem querying records with authors but I could not pull out records with no authors. I base such assumption that there are books with no authors.
Here is my query by the way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Books.title, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Authors.authorname SEPARATOR ', ') AS authors 
FROM Books 
INNER JOIN BooksAuthors USING (bookid) 
INNER JOIN Authors USING (authorid) GROUP BY  books.bookid
```

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN: `.... FROM Books 
LEFT JOIN BooksAuthors USING (bookid) ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bookid, title FROM Books INNER JOIN (
    SELECT bookid FROM BooksAuthors WHERE authorid IS NULL) AS T1
ON Books.bookid = T1.bookid;
```

This will basically do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try yo use LEFT JOIN, and maybe you will need the extra adding **HAVING** part ... try without and with and see what you get

```
SELECT DISTINCT Books.title, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Authors.authorname SEPARATOR ', ') AS authors 
FROM Books 
INNER JOIN BooksAuthors ON BooksAuthors.bookid = Books.bookid
LEFT JOIN Authors ON Authors.authorid = BooksAuthors.authorid
GROUP BY books.bookid
HAVING Authors.authorid IS NOT NULL
```